# Is there any way to communicate from Perl to PHP using internal redirect and apache_notes?

Tags: php, perl, apache

My main app is written using PHP, but I'm using a Perl script to process a request, and I want to pass information to the PHP app using apache_notes. I would prefer not to use query parameters.

Here's the documentation on apache notes I found

- [for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-note.php)
- [for Perl](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_notes_)

On the PHP documentation, there is an example of how to use apache notes from PHP->Perl. Does anyone have an example of how to go from Perl->PHP, or suggest another way to securely communicate from Perl to PHP without having to go through query parameters?

Comment: The example in the PHP documentation shows both directions. Don't you see the comment that says "Pass result back to PHP"?

Comment: The rewrite goes to perl first before it goes into php. The php example starts in php then writes to perl and then gets the result back. I want to find a way to do it starting from perl. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So your question isn't really about the communication, but how the Perl script starts the PHP script, the Perl equivalent of PHP's `virtual` function. See http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/SubRequest.html

Comment: I have tried perl's internal_redirect already. At the time of the redirect, I have set the apache notes and verified that they were in fact, set. However, when it reaches php, the notes seem to be empty. I couldn't find any code examples online of this working either...

Comment: Please post your code, maybe someone can see an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$r->subprocess_env("foo", $value)`, which from PHP will be visible as `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_foo"]`.